# Migrating SSRS 2008 Reports/Report Models to SSRS 2019?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've read thru several threads on "Report Model" migration from older 2008 SSRS and the consensus indicates it simply can't be done and I will need to convert all the Report Models to "something else" (I'm assuming Stored Procedure from a data source).  I foolishly thought this would be easy until I couldn't find any actual query/stored procedure or anything that mapped report column to actual field ... this information is not present in the SMDL file either (which as far as I can tell is an XML format).  I can't find where or how the SMDL identifies a query or stored procedure use to generate a dataset the report references?

The migrated report shows a Dataset with report columns, but the Query Type is "text" and that text consists of the same XML found in the SMDL.  I can't find anything that suggests how the Dataset is populated?

Answer (score 1):

There are logs on the report server with names like **ReportServerService__05_17_2023_00_08_20.log** which appear to capture the SQL generated by report model reports. It's not the prettiest SQL code in the world, possibly not the most efficient, and you have to run each report and then go get the SQL from the log.  You have to figure out what values may have been parameters which the generated SQL shows as literals...

Bottom line is, it's not fun, but it's the only way I've found so far to convert report-model based to SQL based datasets. I find using SQL Prompt from Redgate helps... it won't capture the SQL for you but it can at least reformat the generated SQL into something more like your preferred coding style...